# How to run php code in VSCode in Ubuntu 20.04, when it was installed with XAMPP server?

Tags: php, lamp, xampp, visual-studio-code

I want to execute php files on VSCode (php was installed with XAMPP server), so I find the executable path of my php with `whereis php`, after this I got: `php: /opt/lampp/bin/php` , so on VSCode settings.json file I added:

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "/opt/lampp/bin/php"
```

Then when using Code Runner VSCode extension, when trying to right clic and Run Code, I got `/bin/sh: 1: php: not found` on console.

I wonder how to run php code in VSCode.

Comment: I can not answer your question, but I find it funny that people are installing third-party bundles like XAMPP on Linux, instead of native system packages for Apache, PHP & whatever. XAMPP-type bundles were born in Windows world, as port of native Linux software that was not available on Windows. Then someone ported that port back to Linux and people started using it, instead of original packages that were the basis of it. Funny :)

Comment: @raj, great observation. I'm new to php, and I was trying to run a github project that specifies to run files with xampp server, so I installed php by xampp.